# putImageData says the provided ImageData object isn't an ImageData object, but when it's printed to the console it shows it is

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I used getImageData to save the pixels of an image in a two dimensional array and I'm now trying to draw them with putImageData, but I'm getting an error saying the first parameter is not of type ImageData. However, when I print the variable out to the console it tells me it is an ImageData object and I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

In my code I have the following:

```
console.log(this.imageData[xPoint][yPoint]);
this.context.putImageData(this.imageData[xPoint][yPoint], column, row);
```

and in the console it outputs:

`ImageData {data: Uint8ClampedArray(4), width: 1, height: 1, colorSpace: 'srgb'}`

followed by:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'putImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': parameter 1 is not of type 'ImageData'.`

This confuses me as the console shows it as ImageData but then it says it isn't an ImageData type, so I was wondering what it is I'm doing wrong?

I don't know if this helps, but if I do:

`console.log(this.imageData[xPoint][yPoint].data);`

I get:

`Uint8ClampedArray(4) [127, 127, 127, 255, buffer: ArrayBuffer(4), byteLength: 4, byteOffset: 0, length: 4, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Uint8ClampedArray']`

followed by:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')`

Which also seems odd to me as it could read the data property when it outputted it to the console but then it says it can't read it (both these messages are to do with the same line of code)? Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this?

Comment: the three leading parameters require comma separation?

Answer (score 0):

Typically the ImageData object stores all the data for a single image.  You appear to be indexing it as if it were a two dimensional array of pixels.

What happens if you instead try:

```
this.context.putImageData(this.imageData, 0, 0)
```

?